# uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Json despite "require 'active_support/all'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest-client, activesupport

I'm receiving a "uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Json" error on the line where I call `responseJson = ActiveSupport::Json.decode(response)`, in a small controller in my small Rails app.

The `response` variable returns a string with a response of the type `{"token":"this_is_your_session_token"}`.

I've added `gem 'activesupport', '~> 4.2.3'`, to my `Gemfile`, tried different `require` statements with `'active_support/core_ext/object/json`, and tried this in the IRB (with the same error). I'm not sure how to debug this further. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## require 'active_support/json'

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/all'
require 'rest-client'

class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def login_attempt
    username = params[:u]
    password = params[:p]

    puts "waiting on request"
    response = RestClient.post 'http://localhost:3001/v1/login', :email => username, :password => password
    responseJson = ActiveSupport::Json.decode(response)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveSupport::JSON (all caps). FYI, if you use pry instead of irb, you can run a command like 'ls ActiveSupport' and see the contained modules, methods, etc.